# Calling a variable in VBA Formula

Tags: vba, variables

I am very new in VBA and have the following problem:

I have a code like this

```
IE.Document.getElementsByName("selectedNotifiers")(tparty).Checked = True
```

The purpose is to check a checkbox on a website. The code works. Now I want to use tparty as a variable based on a excel cell.

I tired this

```
Dim tparty As String
tparty = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Value(Range("q" & rn))
IE.Document.getElementsByName("selectedNotifiers")(tparty).Checked = True
```

but is causing the IE crashing. Any help plz.

Latest status. even Tried this

```
Dim tparty As String
tparty = "SFD0087G"
IE.Document.getElementsByName("selectedNotifiers")(tparty).Checked = True
```

no luck.

Comment: use `tparty = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("q" & rn).Value`

Comment: Thanks. But didn't work. IE crashed :(

Comment: use Immediate Window to check the value of `rn` and correspondent `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("q" & rn).Value`

Comment: sorry.. but didn't work. I also tried this [Dim tparty As String
tparty = "SFD0087G"
IE.Document.getElementsByName("selectedNotifiers")(tparty).Checked = True
End Sub] its giving error "sever sends and exception"

Comment: Did you make those checks I asked you in my previous comment?

Comment: yes, I did. but no luck

Comment: And what were the returned values of those two expressions?

Comment: rn returned 2 and the correspondent was SFD0087G

Comment: and with your original code  `IE.Document.getElementsByName("selectedNotifiers")(tparty).Checked = True` what was the value of `tparty` the made the it work?

Comment: ok I solved it. partly. if tparty is integer, it works, but if tparty is string, it doesn't. originally, without tparty, an alphanumeric value was working.